# How can i get the data from firestore using iniState to get the widget

Tags: flutter, pdf, google-cloud-firestore

Im currently creating a pdf report where i can get all the data collection and it's field to be able to appear in the pdf file using widget, now i cant seem to figure it out how to make it appear, and i tried using this method.

So i tried this method to get the data from the firestore

```
class _testingState extends State<testing> {
  final CollectionReference collectionUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ratings');
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();




   String? date;

  void initState(){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("ratings")
        .doc(dateStr)
        .collection('failed rating')
        .snapshots();
    setState((){
      

      date = widget.['date'];
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: What is this suposed to do: `date = widget.['date'];`?

Comment: super.initState() belongs at the beginning of initState, not the end.

Comment: date = widget.['date']; i think it suppose to get the data from the firebase?

Comment: it is always good to give time for learning something, I guess you should start with learning the Dart programming language and its syntax.. before involving with Flutter and Firebase. in your code snippet, the `widget.['date']` has no sense and its syntax is wrong, the `widget` property is used in the `State` object to access it's `StatefulWidget` properties, the `...['date']` is used usually to get values from a `Map`, in addition, that putting`snapshots()` just like this has no effect on your code, and `setState` as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.